# Sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor x^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, irrational-numbers

Can we find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor x^n$ explicitly? The question is related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448064/sum-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-lfloor-nr-rfloor-xn-where-r-is-rati/3448162#3448162) where sum is computed if $\sqrt{2}$ is replaced by some rational number $r$.

Comment: Have you followed the link in the question you pointed to, and read Eq. (4) and (5) of what it references? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

Comment: Yes I did check the references as well. I don't find the method  efficient for computations.

Comment: There probably isn't known any closed form -- http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C8%2C8&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a solution but it does yield a representation that has a nice approximation built into it.  Note the series representation
$$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor =x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi }\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{\sin \left( 2\pi kx \right)}{k}}$$
And so
$${{B}_{1}}\left( \left\{ x \right\} \right)=\left\{ x \right\}-\frac{1}{2}=x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{\pi }\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{\sin \left( 2\pi kx \right)}{k}}$$
Where ${{B}_{1}}$is a Bernoulli polynomial and $\left\{ x \right\}$  is the fractional part of $x$.  Substituting and evaluating some series we have
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\left\lfloor an \right\rfloor {{x}^{n}}}=\frac{ax}{{{\left( x-1 \right)}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2\left( x-1 \right)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{{{B}_{1}}\left( \left\{ an \right\} \right){{x}^{n}}}$$
Taking say the first term we get a good approximation

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\left\lfloor an \right\rfloor {{x}^{n}}}\simeq \frac{ax}{{{\left( x-1 \right)}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2\left( x-1 \right)}+\frac{1}{2}$$

For $a=\sqrt{2}$  quick graphs highlight how reasonable the approximations indeed are.  The first graph below shows the numerical evaluation of the series (black dashed), against the Bernoulli polynomial approximation for $n=0,1$ and $n=0,1,2$  (blue and orange respectively), over half the domain so as to highlight the discrepancy.  The second graph shows the $n=0$ approximation over a wider domain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Certainly a good approximation!